# Connect 4 check win method throws index out of bounds error

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The error I receive when checking for a win in my test case is a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error. Sorry if this question may have been asked before, I have already tried looking for other solutions but I couldn't find any. So I'm hoping this is fine. The code for the project can be seen here:

```
public class testClass {
    
    static int[][] board1 = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0},
        };
    
    static int[][] board2 = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };
    
    static int[][] board3 = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };
    
    static int redCount, ylwCount;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        horizontalWin();
        verticalWin();
        diagonalWin();
    }
    
    public static void horizontalWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (board1[5][2 + i] == 1) {
                redCount++;
            } else if (board1[5][2 + i] == 2) {
                ylwCount++;
            }
            
            if (redCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Red wins");
            } else if (ylwCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Yellow wins");
            }
        }
        redCount = 0;
        ylwCount = 0;
    }
    
    public static void verticalWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (board2[1 + i][1] == 1 || board2[1 - i][1] == 1) {
                redCount++;
            } else if (board2[1 - i][1] == 2 || board2[1 - i][1] == 2) {
                ylwCount++;
            }
            
            if (redCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Red wins");
            } else if (ylwCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Yellow wins");
            }
        }
        redCount = 0;
        ylwCount = 0;
    }
    
    public static void diagonalWin() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (board3[5 + i][2 + i] == 1 || board3[5 - i][2 - i] == 1) {
                redCount++;
            } else if (board3[5 + i][2 + i] == 2 || board3[5 - i][2 - i] == 2) {
                ylwCount++;
            }
            
            if (redCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Red wins");
            } else if (ylwCount == 4) {
                System.out.println("Yellow wins");
            }
        }
        redCount = 0;
        ylwCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The stack trace will tell you the statement causing the problem. 2) You then determine why the index is "out of bounds" and then fix the problem. 3) I would guess when you use  "5 + i" you would have a problem. What happens when i =  1 or 2 or 3? You get an index of  6 or 7 or 8 which would be "out of bounds". Java indexes are 0 based. So if you have 6 rows, the maximum index can only be 5.

Comment: @camickr So I should check if adding 4 to each row or col would result in a value greater than the index boundaries before checking for pieces in a row?

Comment: Your looping conditions should NOT allow you to go outside the bounds of the array. That is the purpose of using the for loop. You can control the starting and ending indexes. So the question is why would you start at index 5? So you need to alter your logic. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In the method diagonalWin(), board3[5+i][2+i] exceeds the dimensions of board3(which is 7X6).

Once i = 1 : board3[5 + i][2 + i] = board[6][3]

And board[6][3] does not exist in the array.